# How to check if a topic was consumed by a consumer in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

How should one check if a specific consumer group, fully consumed a topic?
This is the equivalent of checking if a queue is empty in standard queuing system.
This isn't obvious as each consumer only see the partitions it is given hence it isn't aware if other consumers in it's group consumed their part.
I guess this should be done somehow by `AdminUtils` or `ZkUtils` but I cant seem to find the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to check consumer offset.
(The kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh has similar functionality but has been deprecated in 0.9.0.0.)

> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxx:9092--group
>   xxx-group-id --describe --new-consumer
>   GROUP TOPIC PARTITION 
>   CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET LAG OWNER consumer.test.0529.095217
>   secured_topic 0 586 3333 2747 consumer-1_/10.139.0.4
>   consumer.test.0529.095217 secured_topic 3334 3334 0
>   consumer-1_/10.139.0.4 consumer.test.0529.095217 secured_topic 2 0
>   3333 3333 consumer-1_/10.139.0.4