# How to find the offset range for a topic-partition in Kafka 0.10?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm using Kafka 0.10.0. Before processing, I want to know the size of the records in a partition.

In 0.9.0.1 version, I used to find the difference between `latest` and `earliest` offset for a partition by using the below code. In the new version, it gets stuck when retrieving the `consumer#position` method.

```
package org.apache.kafka.example.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.Range;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class FindTopicRange {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public FindTopicRange() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static Map<TopicPartition, Range<Long>> getOffsets(String topic) {

        Map<TopicPartition, Range<Long>> partitionToRange = new HashMap<>();
        try (KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getConsumerConfigs())) {

            List<TopicPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : consumer.partitionsFor(topic)) {
                partitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic(), partitionInfo.partition()));
            }
            consumer.assign(partitions);

            for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
                consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.singletonList(partition));
                long earliestOffset = consumer.position(partition);

                consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(partition));
                long latestOffset = consumer.position(partition);
                partitionToRange.put(partition, Range.between(earliestOffset, latestOffset));
            }
            return partitionToRange;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while getting offset range information for topic : {}", topic, e);
        }
        return partitionToRange;
    }

    private static Properties getConsumerConfigs() {
        Properties configs = new Properties();
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 10240);

        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
        configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
        return configs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getOffsets("hello"));
    }

}
```

Stacktrace for the above call is shown below:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1750013800 nid=0x443 runnable [0x00007f1756b88000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x00000007c21cba00> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000007c21cb9f0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000007c21cb8d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:454)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.fetchCommittedOffsets(ConsumerCoordinator.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.refreshCommittedOffsetsIfNeeded(ConsumerCoordinator.java:306)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateFetchPositions(KafkaConsumer.java:1405)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1196)
```

Comment: Is any other method available to fetch the `latest` and `earliest` offset without instantiating `KafkaConsumer` ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make your example work in scala (was already working on similar code).  The only addition that I made was adding a consumer.poll to the code given that both consumer.subscribe and consumer.assign are lazy.

```
val partitions = new util.ArrayList[TopicPartition]

for (partitionInfo <- consumer.partitionsFor(topic)) {
 partitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic, partitionInfo.partition))}

 val recordTemp = consumer.poll(1000)

 for (partition <- partitions) {
    consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.singletonList(partition))
    println(consumer.position(partition))
    consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(partition))
    println(consumer.position(partition))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to fake it with a new consumer group?  This post shows that it can give you the lag values [other method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505464/715947)