# Spark Streaming Kafka initial offset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using the Java Spark API, for the KafkaUtils.createDirectStream, I want to track the offset.
There is a parameter called fromOffset, which records the offset in partitions of the Kafka topic. for the first run, I have no idea of how many partitions I will have, then how can I set this parameter?
And will I need set "auto.offset.reset" in Kafka parameters?
If yes, will it affect my code to recover from an known offset?

Comment: If you don't know the number of partitions, how do you know starting offset for each partition?

Comment: If I set the "auto.offset.reset" to smallest or largest, I can still get the partition and offset info from each red

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

- in case you don't have any information about partions, do not provide that param to createDirectStream. There are several implmentations of createDirectStream method. In that case or earliest, or latest offset per each topicPartition will be used (based on the `auto.offset.reset` param)
- you can find the partitions, offsets using usual kafka API. For example look [How to find the offset range for a topic-partition in Kafka 0.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545245/how-to-find-the-offset-range-for-a-topic-partition-in-kafka-0-10)

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway for Kafka 0.8? as 0.10 is experimental API